# Python: print the value of a given key from two dictionaries

Tags: dictionary

I am working upon two dictionaries as "first" & "second". I want to find out the value of a given key as "version" though i don't know "version" key is present on which dictionary. & at the end i am writing the value to file.
Here "fo" is file object.

code here:

```
for version in first.iteritems():
   for version in second.iteritems():
       fo.write("value of version is :"????????)
```

I tried with it but i don't know what to write on the mentioned question mark.

Comment: first = dict(version = 4.4.4, id = 2222)
second = dict(abc = 0, cde = 3)

output should write to file as 4.4.4

Comment: above is a example but i don't know where the version key is present

Comment: Hari, 4.4.4 is not a valid input .. it should '4.4.4'.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
first = dict(version = '4.4.4', id = 2222) 
second = dict(abc = 0, cde = 3)

for key1,key2 in zip(first.keys(),second.keys()):
    if key1 == 'version':
        #fo.write("value of version is :",first[key1])
        print "value of version is:",first[key1]
    if key2 == 'version':
        #fo.write("value of version is :",second[key2])
        print "value of version is:",second[key2]
```

OUTPUT

```
value of version is: 4.4.4
```

Please let me know it works for you.